# NSolve not working

Tags: equation-solving

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but for some reason NSolve isn't working for me. Here's what I'm trying to do.

```
f1[x_] := (4 - x^2)^(1/2)
f2[x_] := -x*Cot[x]

NSolve[f1[x] == f2[x], x]

During evaluation of In[50]:= Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered. >>

During evaluation of In[50]:= NSolve::naqs: 2==Indeterminate is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities. >>

NSolve[2 == Indeterminate, 0]
```

I know there is a solution, because I did it on a different numerical solver and I got 1 result equal to 1.895494....

I'm a totally newbie at Mathematica so again, sorry if this is a simple question. I tried my best to figure out how to make it work but I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I get a different error message, `NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve. >>`  Some expressions are too difficult for `NSolve`.  In such cases, use `FindRoot` instead.  It gives your expected answer.

Comment: This works: `NSolve[f1[x] == f2[x] && -3 < x < 3, x]`. I arrived at this after I had a look at the plot `Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, -5, 5}]`.

Answer (score 3):

No dumb at all,

```
Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, -π, π}]
```

[image]

As commented by @StephenLuttrell [NSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) works with intervalls quite well;

```
NSolve[f1[x] == f2[x] && -3 < x < 3, x]
```

> ```
> {{x -> -1.89549}, {x -> 1.89549}}
> ```

As well [FindInstance](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html?q=FindInstance) and [FindRoot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html?q=FindRoot)

```
FindInstance[f1[x] == f2[x], x] // N // Chop
```

> ```
> {{x -> 1.89549}}
> ```

```
FindRoot[f1[x] == f2[x], {x, -2}] // Chop
```

> ```
> {x -> -1.89549}
> ```

So, you'll find the Intersections with:

```
pts = {x, f2[x]} /. FindRoot[f1[x] == f2[x], {x, #}] & /@ {-2, 2} // 
  Chop
```

> ```
> {{-1.89549, 0.638045}, {1.89549, 0.638045}}
> ```

```
Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, -π, π}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[pts]}]
```

[image]