# How to solve this example `x^2=2^x`?

Tags: equation-solving

How to solve this? I don't know, and ask you ))

$$
x^2=2^x;
$$

Comment: `Solve[x^2 == 2^x, x]`

Comment: with `Solve[]`.  That said i'm guessing this is not a mathematica (software) question and you should try math.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question is similar in character to [96162] (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96162/nsolve-not-working) and can be answered in the same way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems unrelated to Mathematica.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
soln = Solve[x^2 == 2^x, x, Reals] // FullSimplify

(*  {{x -> 2}, 
   {x -> -((2*ProductLog[Log[2]/2])/
            Log[2])}, {x -> 4}}  *)

% // N

(*  {{x -> 2.}, {x -> -0.766665}, {x -> 4.}}  *)
```

See MathWorld [Lambert W-Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html)

```
Plot[{x^2, 2^x}, {x, -1, 4.2}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[{x, x^2} /. soln]}]
```

[image]

Or use [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com)

```
WolframAlpha["solve x^2 == 2^x for real x"]
```

[image]